# Display related post by tag name of current post

Tags: posts, tags

I am using thesis and i am trying to display the related post by there tag name.

suppose i have post and that post have three tag or multiple

tag like tag:- 1) car, 2)automobile, 3) mechanical

so i want display the related post by the tag name of car,automobile,mechanical.

I am trying the bellow code with the thesis hook but its not displaying the related post by the tag name of that post its displaying another related post which have don't have any connection with these three tags of this post.

so any body can tell hot do this.

my function code:-

```
function tagpost(){
        global $post;
        $tag = get_the_tags();
        foreach ($tag as $tags){
                 ?>
       <div class="relatedpostAdd post<?php echo $tags->term_id; ?>">
        <h3 style="margin:5px 0 "><?php echo $tags->name; ?></h3>
    <ul>
<?php
        $posts = get_posts('numberposts=6&term_id='. $tags->term_id);
        foreach($posts as $post) {
        ?>
    <li>
    <div class="images_releted">
        <a class="post_thumbnail" href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" 
          title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?>
        </a>
    </div>
        <a class="post_thumbnail_link" href="<? the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark" 
         title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a>               
    </li>

<?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php } 
}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_post_box_related_posts','tagpost');
```

Comment: Your `get_posts` arguments are wrong. Use `tag_id`, not `term_id`

Comment: see i have chaged it to 'get_posts('numberposts=6&term='. $tags->tag_id);' but same issue post not pointing to related 'tag' shall i use tag instead of 'term' in 'ger_posts' argument

Comment: @PieterGoosen i have changed it displaying wrong related post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in a comment, your `get_posts` parameters are wrong. There is no such parameter as  `term_id`. You should make use `tag` which uses the tag slugs as a string or `tag__in` which uses the tag ids in an array

This will work

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=6&tag='. $tags->slug);
```

or this will work

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=6&tag__in=' . array( $tags->term_id ));
```

There are some other issues as well that I want to highlight here

- You should set the post ID in [`get_the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags). Do something like this `get_the_tags( $post->ID );`
- Set the plural name as the variable name which will hold your array from your function and use the single name as your `value` in your `foreach` loop. This eliminates confusion and is easier to debug. If you read this, `$tags->name`, you immediately think of more than one tag, yet this is used to retrieve the specific tag's name as `$tags` are actually your value. You should do something like this which IMO is far better to understand and less confusing

  ```
  $tags = get_the_tags();
  foreach ( $tags as $tag ){
      echo $tag->name;
  }
  ```

**EDIT**

To exclude the current post, you can do the following

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=6&tag__in=' . array( $tags->term_id ) . '&post__not_in=' . array( $post->ID) );
```

Comment: great answer its working great but have one issue  is this possible to hide related post which is display as main post

Comment: you are getting me right but i am confusing where to place this code in get post

Comment: See my update. Added comment to answer

Comment: ok fine i get it

Comment: i was try this updated code but its not displaying related post it displaying only tag heading of current post

Comment: now i am getting Internal Server Error on post details page with this updated code

Comment: Sorry, I'm posting from my phone, tough coding :-). See update